# jQuery UI Slider: access options from function associated with the slide event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, uislider

I have a slider defined in this way:

```
$( "#myslider").slider({
    range: true,
    min: min_val,
    max: max_val,
    values: [ min_val, max_val ],
    slide: function(event, ui){
        $('#input_min').val(ui.values[0]);
        $('#input_max').val(ui.values[1]);
    },
});
```

Where `min_val` and `max_val` can change.

Now let's say that in the function associated with the slide event I want to check if the current min and max values are different from the initial ones.

I know I can access the current values with `ui.values` and I can get the initial min and max with the following code:

```
var inital_min = $( "#myslider").slider("option", "min");
var inital_max = $( "#myslider").slider("option", "max");
```

but this looks dumb to me, because I already have the `ui` object from the callback.

I tried to navigate the object with firebug but I could not locate what I'm looking for.

So, is there any other way to get these values?

Comment: You may have a look at the slide callback context `this` it might be the input itself from which you can make these slider calls to get the initial options back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use this to access it.  I put it fiddle for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/dhQk/vr2Mg/

```
var i_max = $(this).slider('option', 'max');
var i_min = $(this).slider('option', 'min');
```

Unfortunately no local object will have it according to the official references. 
http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide

Answer (score 0):

The min_val and max_val variables can be reused inside your slide callback.

Answer (score 0):

This is really not true, you could get the slider object and access to them inside a method, using event object:

```
$(event.target).slider("option","max")
```